# Basic Authentication of Squid 4.5 - /usr/lib64/squid/basic_ncsa_auth file not found

Tags: basic-authentication, squid, centos7.6

I have centos 7.6 & installed squid 4.5 on it.

```
sudo yum -y install squid
```

I followed this [link](https://hostpresto.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-squid-proxy-on-centos-7/) for `Basic Authentication`.
Without authentication squid works fine.
Here is `squid.conf` file after adding `# Basic Authentication` part :

```
#
# Recommended minimum configuration:
#

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt to list your (internal) IP networks from where browsing
# should be allowed
acl localnet src 0.0.0.1-0.255.255.255  # RFC 1122 "this" network (LAN)
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8     # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src 100.64.0.0/10      # RFC 6598 shared address space (CGN)
acl localnet src 169.254.0.0/16     # RFC 3927 link-local (directly plugged) machines
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12      # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16     # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src fc00::/7           # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10          # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

#
# Recommended minimum Access Permission configuration:
#
# Deny requests to certain unsafe ports
http_access deny !Safe_ports

# Deny CONNECT to other than secure SSL ports
# http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

# Only allow cachemgr access from localhost
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager

# We strongly recommend the following be uncommented to protect innocent
# web applications running on the proxy server who think the only
# one who can access services on "localhost" is a local user
#http_access deny to_localhost

#
# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS
#

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt localnet in the ACL section to list your (internal) IP networks
# from where browsing should be allowed
http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost

# Basic Authentication
auth_param basic program /usr/lib64/squid/basic_ncsa_auth /etc/squid/passwd
auth_param basic children 5
auth_param basic realm Squid Basic Authentication
auth_param basic credentialsttl 2 hours
acl auth_users proxy_auth REQUIRED
http_access allow auth_users

# allow all requests    
acl all src 0.0.0.0/0
http_access allow all

# And finally deny all other access to this proxy
http_access deny all

# Squid normally listens to port 3128
http_port 3128

# Uncomment and adjust the following to add a disk cache directory.
#cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid 100 16 256

# Leave coredumps in the first cache dir
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid

#
# Add any of your own refresh_pattern entries above these.
#
refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:    1440    0%  1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0%  0
refresh_pattern .       0   20% 4320
```

Please see `# Basic Authentication` part.
The problem is :
 `/usr/lib64/squid/basic_ncsa_auth` file not exist.
Where is that file?
How can i fix this problem & What is the correct configuration of squid 4.5?

Answer (score 7):

```
auth_param basic program /usr/lib/squid/basic_ncsa_auth /etc/squid/passwd
```

Answer (score 0):

for squid v4:

```
yum install squid-helpers
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the path for basic_ncsa_auth library:

## Basic Authentication

auth_param basic program /usr/lib64/squid/basic_ncsa_auth /etc/squid/passwd

for:

## Basic Authentication

auth_param basic program /usr/lib/squid/basic_ncsa_auth /etc/squid/passwd

this will work :)